# Why does a combined upper and lower bound comparison always evaluate to true?

Tags: c++, syntax, evaluation, comparison-operators

Why does the first always evaluate to true? I would expect these two statements to behave identically.

```
   for (int i =0;i<4;++i) (0 < i < 3) ? cout << "True " : cout << "False ";
```

> True True True True

```
    for (int i =0;i<4;++i) (0 < i && i < 3) ? cout << "True " : cout << "False ";
```

> False True True False

Comment: `(0 < i < 3)` -- You will soon discover that C++ is not algebra.

Comment: dont confuse maths notation with c++ syntax, there are similarities (eg an expression like `0 < i` is either true or false) but the differences outweigh them. Maybe the most prominent example is `x = 3*y;` which is not an equation, but an assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition `0 < i < 3` is really `(0 < i) < 3`.

And it doesn't matter if `0 < i` is true or not, as the result (`0` for false and `1` for true) will *always* be less than `3`.

If you want to make sure `i` is within a range, you need multiple *separate* comparisons: `0 < i && i < 3`, as you do in the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because no combined comparison operator exists in C++. The expression is evaluated as

```
(0 < i) < 3
```

but `x < 1` evaluates to `true`/`false` which evaluates to `1`/`0` when compared with an `int` so in the end `0 < 3` is always true and `1 < 3` too.